# Deploying django under a sub-URL with Nginx/Fastcgi

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I can't for the life of me figure out how to deploy a django site under a non-root location with Nginx/fastcgi, e.g. http://localhost:8080/myproject/ instead of http://localhost:8080/; all the examples I have seen either assume Apache or mounting at the root of the site. Here's the relevant part of my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /myproject/ {
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;

        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
}
```

And a minimal `urls.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello$', lambda request: HttpResponse('Hello world!')),
```

)

Trying to access http://localhost:8080/myproject/hello gives a 404. I've tried unsuccessfully all combinations of:

- Commenting/uncommenting `fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;`
- Commenting/uncommenting `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;`
- Setting `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/myproject/'` in settings.py.

Answer (score 7):

Just pushed through the same issue myself- it turns out that the link you provided on ServerFault to the [Django change doc](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ChangedthewayURLpathsaredetermined) was the key to solving the problem.

Django > 1.0 uses `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_INFO` to route URLs, as the doc explained. So I took that and ran with it. For a project called 'myproject', which you'd like rooted at mydomain.com/myproject/, try this.

```
location ~ /myproject/(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO /$1;
    SCRIPT_NAME /myproject;
}
```

The rest of the fastcgi params I have in another site-wide config file. So your example would look something like

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /myproject/ {
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;

        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        /myproject;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          /$1;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
}
```

with the same urls.py. The only issues I've had so far have been minor troubles keeping DRY, eg where settings.py requires absolute URLs and Django doesn't think to prepend the `SCRIPT_NAME` on the URL (think `settings.LOGIN_URL`, `settings.MEDIA_URL`).

This might be obvious, but also make sure you have another location that points to your static and admin media.

Comment: @gsakkis, did this help you at all?

Comment: It helped me... I hosted two webapps on same server{} in nginx.conf using this method. but my problem is both requires different static and media url... what to do here ??

Answer (score 3):

Try this conf

```
    location  /myproject {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/myproject)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

where, fastcgi_params file contains

```
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;

    # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
    fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

It worked for me.

see documentation about [fastcgi_split_path_info](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled over your question as I had the sub-URL problem myself. My server uses Apache as its main server, so my configuration is different, but it works. Maybe this will help somebody:

- Apache on port 80 (main web server)
- nginx on localhost:3033 (random port)
- manage.py fastcgi on localhost:3034

Then the Apache config looks like this (proxy to nginx):

```
<Location /blogsite/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3033/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3033/
</Location>
```

And the nginx site configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:3033;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3034;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/blogsite.access_log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/blogsite.error_log;
}
```

I think the problem you have is due to the nginx configuration somehow, not really a problem with Django deployment. You may want to try out if my posted solution works for you.